# redirect https:// to http:// bypassing the "Add Exception" page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

For some reasons Google custom search result shows https:// for some of my page links. The only solution for now would be to redirect the https:// links to http:// with htaccess for now until i figure out why search results are showing https://

I want the redirect to bypass the SSL cretificate or "Add Exception" page and redirect to http://

Answer (score 1):

You won't be be able to do this with .htaccess because for the client to get the redirect it will have to have already started the SSL session (and therefore shown the add exception page)  The only way around this is to buy a real certificate signed by a trusted CA.

Answer (score 0):

You could also sign up for Cloudflare HTTPS. They offer it free of charge right now. You can then enable SSL on the entire site, and redirect to HTTP, or HTTPS. Your choice. This would prevent the warning from being issued.